docker compose up -d does not recognize the -d
I have a docker-compose.yml file and when I try to do:
sudo docker compose up -d

I get:
unknown shorthand flag: 'd' in -d
See 'docker --help'.



Usage:  docker [OPTIONS] COMMAND

This question is similar to unknown shorthand flag: 'd' in -d docker compose but the answer to that question is the one that I have problems with
Notice also that I am not using docker-compose.
Is it perhaps that the -d option has been deprecated or perhaps my version does not have it yet?
docker compose version
Docker Compose version v2.3.4

EDIT:
I found the solution. It is strange but this happens when run with sudo. When I did run without sudo it worked
The hint was that docker compose up --help actually mentioned the detached option

2.3.4 is quite old, upgrading might be a start. But compose up -d is literally mentioned in those notes, so it should be supported. You can also check what flags a command does recognise by reading its help: docker compose up --help.

Try to update Docker Compose. v2.3.4 is old. I've checked for v2.20.2 and it's working fine

That's weird, even v2.3.4 should support this flag as per documentation.

How can I cleanly update docker compose? my docker -version is 19.03.13

Should I do sudo apt-get install docker-compose-plugin?

If you installed the compose plugin only for your user, running docker as root won't have it available. In any case, drop the habit of prefixing random things with sudo.
